Can't execute a python script converted to .exe file due to a problem when trying to read a .txt file
I'm encountering a FileNotFoundError when converting my Python script to an executable (.exe) using PyInstaller. The error occurs when the program tries to read a text file that exists in the working directory.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
import os
from docx import Document
from docx2pdf import convert

doct = 'PDF.docx'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\JUSanche\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI2642\\searchdata.txt'
docn = 'Reporte de búsqueda.docx'

data_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
data_relative_path = "searchdata.txt"
data_full_path = os.path.join(data_dir_path, data_relative_path)
ubicaciondocx = os.path.join(data_dir_path, docn)

# ... (rest of the code)

doc.save(ubicaciondocx)
pdf_name = docn.replace('.docx', '.pdf')
convert(ubicaciondocx, pdf_name)
os.startfile(pdf_name)

The issue: When running the .py file, everything works correctly. However, after converting to .exe, I get this error:
Exact error message:
enter image description here
FileNotFoundError: 
#Comment: 
#Expected result: C:/GENSET-POWER-TABLE/Genset-Power-Table/searchdata.txt
#Result: C:/Users/JUSanche/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI2642/searchdata.txt

For converting my py file to .exe I used:
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole modificar_doc.py
What I've tried: I've attempted various methods to get the correct file path:

os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

os.getcwd()

os.path.realpath()


These all work correctly when running the .py file, but fail when running the .exe.
Questions:

Why is the .exe looking in a different directory than the .py file?

How can I ensure the .exe finds the correct file path for searchdata.txt?

Is there a way to bundle the required text and docx files with the .exe?


Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This question is similar to: How to set up relative paths to make a portable .exe build in PyInstaller with Python 3?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
